# Making Bootstrap Lightbox work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-lightbox

I would like to create a login form using bootstrap lightbox.
The code is as follows:

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                    <li data-type="useico"><a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#test" data-target="#demoLightbox"><img src="~/Content/images/user-icon.png" /></a></li>
                    <li data-type ="scico"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/images/shopping-cart-icon.png" /><div class="nav-text" id="countCart">1</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class='lightbox-content'>
                    <img src="~/Content/images/Logo-DOLPUZ.png">
                    <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What may be missing here?

Comment: `What may be missing here?` Your CSS. Your Javascript. The rest of your document. Difficult to say with just a snippet of your code

Comment: @Moobs i use bootstrap-css, bootstrap-lightbox css and for javascript i also use bootstrap.js and bootstrap-lightbox.js. I using jquery 1.11.1 . I hope that make my question clearly. Thank you

Comment: can you please create a js fiddle of your code ?